# ListView Click change from another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I have a Listview activity and a Mainactivity.

In my Listview activity i have a array that is

```
public static final String[] link = {
            "http://3313.live.streamtheworld.com/WKRKFM_SC",
            "http://3573.live.streamtheworld.com/KXXRFMAAC",
            "http://2713.live.streamtheworld.com/KXXRFMAAC",
            "http://r16---sn-npo7enel.gvt1.com/videoplayback" };
```

Im using `putExtra` and passing this array to my Mainactivity using this.

```
Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Linkview.class);
    intent.putExtra("link", link[position]);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And i received my extra using this in Mainactivity.

```
final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String link = bundle.getString("link");
```

and i can use it very well but in my MainActivity 
I have a next button

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //??????

            }
        });
```

I want that when i pressed the next button the next array comes from listview activity 
and i can show this in my MainActivity.
How i can do that??

Answer (score 0):

So from your question, I assume you want to show the next item in the array.

As long as you keep your array as a static final variable (i.e. a constant array), you can directly access it from your main class.  You don't need an instance of the class to access a static variable.  For instance, the following should work from your main Activity:

```
        String item = ListviewActivity.link[position];
```

Thus, you can simply pass the position as an integer, look up the string with the above code, and add one to the position to get the next item.

Comment: I want when i click the button next srting will be display@NameSpace

Comment: I cannot see from your code how you are trying to display the String.  I can only see the problem you are having with retrieving the next String.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693145/listview-click-position-changed-from-another-activity

Here i have upload my Total Code just can see this.
and you can understand.@NameSpace